# Google Drive Returning Error 400 in my Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, google-drive-api

I'm following all information about Drive v2 in developers.google.com in order to build a simple app in Android API 15 just to upload a txt file. After many hours spent in all around it like the right java build path for libraries (1.11.0 in my case), enable and set up Drive SDK, API access for client ID, etc, etc. I found a nice example in this post [Google Drive Returning Error 400 or 403 to my Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304535/google-drive-returning-error-400-or-403-to-my-android-app) where I found the same error description that now I'm getting on my app. This is my full code (hope useful to others):

```
public class DrivexampleActivity extends Activity { 

Context activity = null;
boolean alreadyTriedAgain;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    activity = this.getApplicationContext();
    Bundle options = new Bundle();
    Account[] acc = am.getAccounts();
    am.getAuthToken(
        (am.getAccounts())[8], // #8 just in my phone case. you can debugg the acc variable to find your @gmail account index.
        "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE,
        options,
        true, 
        new OnTokenAcquired(),
        null); 
}

private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {

        try {
            final String token = result.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();  

            Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
            b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
                driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);                              
                driveRequest.setKey("xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"); // I replaced the number with x's. for your Client ID from Google API Console
                driveRequest.setOauthToken(token);                      
                }
            }); 

                final Drive drive = b.build();

                final com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
                body.setTitle("My Test File");
                body.setDescription("A Test File");
                body.setMimeType("text/plain");

                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
                final FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain",fileContent);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file;
                        try {                           
                            file = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                            Log.i("Hi", "File ID: " + file.getId());
                            alreadyTriedAgain = false; // Global boolean to make sure you don't repeatedly try too many times when the server is down or your code is faulty... they'll block requests until the next day if you make 10 bad requests, I found.
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            if(!alreadyTriedAgain){
                                alreadyTriedAgain = true;
                                Log.i("Hi", "The upload/insert was caught, which suggests it wasn't successful...");
                                e.printStackTrace();    
                            }    
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

                Intent launch = null;
                launch = (Intent)result.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);

                if (launch != null) {
                    Log.i("Hi", "Something came back as a KEY_INTENT");
                    startActivityForResult(launch, 3025);
                    return; 
                }
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }        
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 3025) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(activity);
                Bundle options = new Bundle();
                am.getAuthToken(
                        (am.getAccounts())[8], // #8 just in my phone case. you can debugg the acc variable to find your @gmail account index.
                        "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE,
                        options,
                        true, 
                        new OnTokenAcquired(),
                        null); 
                break;
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                // This probably means the user refused to log in. Explain to them why they need to log in.
                break;
            default:
                // This isn't expected... maybe just log whatever code was returned.
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // Your application has other intents that it fires off besides the one for Drive's log in if it ever reaches this spot. Handle it here however you'd like.
    }
}
```

Also manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.drivexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DrivexampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.test.type"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But allways get the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

Seems that no errors with DRIVE SDK and Drive API in my case. Any suggestion?? please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the Client ID you got from the APIs Console to driveRequest.setKey, however that method is used to set an API Key and not the Client ID. Check the first answer to the other question you mentioned for more details.

Comment: You are right!, using the API Key provided under Simple API Access I got access. Now I'm getting a "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" I thought the document.txt file was created previosly by filecontent??

Comment: FileContent is used to read the content of an existing file on your computer

Comment: So, it was created by java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt"); but where was placed?. I thought this example are uploading a file created programatly.

Comment: No, the file has to be created manually. Read step 1 in https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart#set_up_the_sample

Comment: Solved! Because the app was running in my device on debugg mode, the SDCARD was not allowed/mounted to place the uploading file. Thanks a lot!